# Set opacity of cached ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, tilecache, syntax

Is it possible to set the opacity of a cached Tiled Map service using ESRI JS API?

I am using:

```
var layer;

layer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("URL",
            {"opacity": 0.5});

map.addLayer(layer);
```

This should work with 50% transparency being set to the layer, right?

Answer (score 2):

That will work, but you'll be making dynamic (export) requests to the tiled service rather than using the tiled images.

This should also work:

```
var layer;

layer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("URL",
            {"opacity": 0.5});

map.addLayer(layer);
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLY6a/1/) for an example.

Comment: This did it - even though your code example was the same as mine, I noticed in my authoring code that I had an title case for "Opacity", when I changed this to a lower case "opacity", the constructor was seen by the webpage and the layer loaded with opacity applied.  CASE is v. NB!